# Retrieve original credit card info given a PayPal PNREF

Tags: paypal

I am using PayPal Payflow SDK for Java v4.40

My business requirements don't allow me to store any credit card info (last 4 digits, expiry date, etc) in my app.  But my app might need to access them occasionally.

Is there a way to query for the original credit card info (last 4 digits, expiry date, etc.) given a PayPal PNREF that was obtained from a previous sale transaction?

paypal.payflow.TransactionResponse class has a getAcct() method, but I was not able to figure out how to get payflow to include account info in a TransactionResponse.

Comment: Hi YTW - if your asking for the CC info that went along with a payment, that's encrypted in the PNREF back; not possible. You would have to pull that before you sent it to PayPal. However, if the PNREF is younger than 12 months old you could still use it for a new transaction using the Reference Transaction API function. - Example Reference -Transaction https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#example-reference-transaction

Comment: @GeekNinja Thank you for your time and comments.  I've updated my question to better describe my scenario.  Does payflow provide a function to query card info associated with a PNREF?